# Spring MVC not adding object to parent with Thymeleaf dynamic form

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I have a dynamic form that I created with thymeleaf and everything submits just fine to the database, however the child object, which in this case is `row`, is not being saved to the parent `studySet`.  When I'm in debug mode I can see that the studySet contains an arraylist of however many row objects, but when they're being saved, it's just not being set to the studySet object.

I'll show some code, to see if I'm forgetting to do anything here.  If anyone can see my problem and let me know that would be great.  Thanks in advance

Here's my post method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="createStudySet", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createSetPost (@ModelAttribute StudySet studySet, ModelMap model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

studySet.setUser(user);
user.getStudySet().add(studySet);

List<Row> rows = studySet.getRows();
studySet.setRows(rows);

studySetRepo.save(studySet);   

return "redirect:/answers";
}
```

Also this may be helpful, this is a screenshot of my controller in debug mode, so that you can see that there is rows in the studySet.

[image: Controller Debug]

So, I just want to set those rows to the studySet.  Also I realize that this code is probably useless, but it shows an attempt at what I'm trying to do. `List<Row> rows = studySet.getRows(); studySet.setRows(rows);`.

Also let me know if it would be useful to see my domain objects, and I would add those to the question.

Comment: Have you set a cascade type in your annotation? E.g. for StudySet @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "xy", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)

Comment: I just tried that, and I'm having the same issue